# Grails GORM keywords 'type' and 'sqltype'

Tags: grails

I wonder what the differences are between using keyword "type" and "sqltype" in GORM settings.

```
class User{
    String keywords;
    static mapping={
        keywords sqlType:'text';
    }
}
```

I'm using MySQL as database. Basically this keywords variable will store a long string typically more than 200 words. I followed some instructions on stackoverflow to specify its GORM mapping but not sure whether to use "type" or "sqltype". I heard "sqltype" is more specific to MySQL. Could anyone please give me a clearer explanation on this?

Also it seems this setting is causing me trouble with "Incorrect string" error.
`Incorrect string value: '\xAC\xED\x00\x05sr...' for column 'keywords' at row 1` [\xAC\xED\x00\x05sr... is a magic number for Java serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687164/mysql-utf-encoding) It seems this sqltype setting has some special effects? (I do have all charset in MySQL as utf8mb4)

Appreciate your suggestion or elaboration!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see using the ***type*** mapping will rely on Java's java.sql.Types (and some other mapping types added to GORM) this will allow you to switch from different databases without to much problem.

In the other hand using ***sqltype*** will use a Database specific Data type, in that case it may not work in other RDBMS without some extra work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will migrate sqltype to type to ensure more flexibility:P